# ScrollView for TableLayout doesn't scroll

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a LinearLayout inside which I have a `ScrollView` for a `TableLayout` inside the `LinearLayout`.

I want to scroll along the `TAbleLayout` which adds content dynamically. But it doesn't work. I have given 60dp for the `LinearLayout` and not `wrap_content` so that it doesn't stretch as the list goes on. And there's an outer scrollview for all other layouts too.

This is the part of the xml.

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    >

                    <TableLayout
                        android:id="@+id/cashOutTableLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="15dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"
                        android:gravity="center">


                    </TableLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are you using scrollview inside scrollview?

Comment: @vrundpurohit yes..the outer scrollview is for the entire layout

Comment: that is why it is not scrolling. use NestedScrollView instead.

Comment: post your whole layout..!!

Comment: @vrundpurohit. it worked. thanks. i had to use `<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`